# Deploying SharePoint Workflow throwing "Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException"

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

While I am trying to activate a SharePoint 2013 platform workflow template from *Manage Site Feature* an exception occurs as in attached.

[image]

I have gone through [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/be41f1c5-1dfb-4869-9a52-1c93902bfd91/microsoftworkflowclientactivitynotfoundexception-when-deploying-solution-with-workflow?forum=sharepointdevelopment), but don't know how to update the **element.xml**.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can download the wsp file (if you know where is on SPO, cause they are talking about SP OnPrem), rename as .cab, edit the Elements.xml through Total Commander, rename again as .wsp file, upload and try again.

or you can try this:

> Always remember to click Publish before saving the wf as a template.

So try recreate the Template from the WF.